# Python can't remove value from nested list

Tags: python, list

I have got this list in python
`[[20.0, 'Harsh'], [20.0, 'Beria'], [19.0, 'Varun'], [19.0, 'Kakunami'], [21.0, 'Vikas']]`
And i want to remove all minimum values from this list,so here is my code

```
g=min(listz)[0];
for value in listz:
    if value[0]==g:
        listz.remove(value);    
        print(value," ",g)
```

But unfortunately this code only removes `Varun` even though `Kakunami` also has the same value.What is the problem?

Comment: When `Varun` is removed, `Kakunami` caves in to takes its place, so `Kakunami` is never checked, as the iteration moves on to the next item after `Varun` (now `Kakunami`) which is `Vikas`

Comment: @MosesKoledoye oh okay,so how can i fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `filter` to do this.

```
g = min(listz)[0];
updated_list = filter(lambda x: x[0] > g, listz)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
new_list = [m for m in listz if m[0]>g]
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers given have not explained the basic problem with your code, which is:
You should not try to mutate the list you are looping through.